# Could not find a declaration file for module 'express'

Tags: typescript, npm, tsconfig, tsc

When I'm running some code looking for a request and response from an express server I'm running into an issue where it cannot find declarations for the module 'express'. This error goes from `Could not find a declaration file for module 'express'.` to `SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`

I tried to use `const express = require('express')`. Next thing I tried was to install the types through npm. I'm wondering if I must create my own type definitions for my server.

```
import express, {request, response} from 'express'; 

const dictionary = {
    "apple": "A round fruit with red or green skin and a white flesh.",
    "banana": "A long curved fruit which grows in clusters and has soft pulpy flesh.",
    "orange": "A spherical fruit with a tough bright reddish-yellow rind.",
  };
  
  const app = express();
  app.use(express.json());
  
  // Define an API endpoint to get a definition for a word
  app.get('/:dictionary', function (req: request, res: response) {
    console.log(req.params[dictionary]);
    res.send();
});
 

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("Server listening on port 3000");
});
```

This is my code.

Answer (score 4):

It seems like you are using es6 import statements to import express but you are not using a module system. To solve that in tsconfig.json file change the module value `commonjs`.

tsconfig.json

```json
"module": "commonjs",
"esModuleInterop": true
```

Then install types

```bash
npm install @types/node @types/express --dev
```